# Problemas en Android Studio con el Fragment que inicia por default

Tags: android, android-fragment

Buenas tardes, Estoy creando una app que implementa un NavigationDrawer, he seleccionado uno de los fragments para que se muestre por default (**Home**), este contiene un ImageView, todo va bien, pero el problema que tengo es que cuando la aplicación está mostrando otro fragment cualquiera en modo vertical, al girar el celular y ponerlo horizontalmente desaparece el fragment que está y vuelve al home. esto no sé donde se controle. El siguiente es el código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Home()).commit();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    boolean FragmentTransaction = false;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {//carga la página principal de la uniagustiniana
        // Handle the camera action
        fragment = new Home();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_portal) {
        fragment = new Portal();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_biblioteca) {
        fragment = new Biblioteca();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_evu) {
        fragment = new Evu();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_directorio) {
        fragment = new Directorio();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_siga) {
        fragment = new Siga();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_moodle) {
        fragment = new Moodle();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_face) {
        fragment = new Facebook();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_twitter) {
        fragment = new Twitter();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_in) {
        fragment = new LinkedIn();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gplus) {
        fragment = new GoogleMas();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
    }

    if(FragmentTransaction){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_main, fragment)
                .commit();

        item.setChecked(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es por que cuando rotas el dispositivo la actividad es recreada y sus metodos se vuelven a ejecutar (comportamiento natural), osea vuelve a ejecutarse la parte de poner tu fragmento "home", lo que puedes hacer es poner esa parte de tu codigo dentro de un if comprobando si el parametro de onCreate "savedInstanceState" es igual a null, ejemplo:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new Home()).commit();
}
```

Con eso cuando el dispositivo gire savedInstanceState ya no sera nula por lo tanto ya no se remplazara tu fragmento.

Comment: #Andres muchas gracias, voy a ensayarlo y ya te cuento como me fue.

Comment: #Andrés, muchísimas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente; yo aprovecharía para preguntarte algo mas, como pudría aplicar saveInstanceState en otros casos, o solo lo usamos en casos como este.